# Unix Diff show invalid missing lines

Tags: unix, compare, logic, diff

I want to compare 2 files line by line.

Unix diff and vimdiff is showing missing lines but these lines are not actually missing. The diff command side-by-side result are not aligned properly. It skips some lines and shows them as missing lines.

Same result shows when I use command diff -a -y -w -t --suppress-common-lines F1 F2.

The link below is an example of the problem state above. It shows some missing lines as marked in blue, but the lines are actually down below.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRuRc.png)

I'm wondering if this is the problem with the logic of unix "diff" command since it only happens on a few file comparison.

Comment: Maybe its is a difference between the way you think it works and the way it actually works. Do you have a way to display the line numbers in your example?

Comment: @J.Chomel I think it's because diff command finds a match of "9 Yr Swap Sensitivity (0.00),0.000010" from both left and right column so it automatically thinks there are missing lines before and after this line. I tried to changed 0.000010 to 0.000011 and the lines got aligned properly. Not sure if it's a flaw in the logic of the diff command.

Comment: I see what you mean now. But it is completely unclear from your question. Please update it if you want anyone relevant (I'm not for such things) to answer.

Comment: But I keep on thinking you have a different logic as the one behind `diff`. If there was such flaw, it would have long been fixed.

Comment: @J.Chomel I manually compared the two files line by line and they have the same lines. The two files have the same number of lines and the only differences are on the numbers in each line. I don't have any logics other than the diff/vimdiff.

Comment: different numbers... different lines! In my view, `diff` do not care about the number of lines in the files. Maybe you can get the code and propose a fork or something.